# Run time or a new idea

Tags: c

I need to write code that sorts in 'n' run time and I don't know how to calculate it. I need to simply sort an array so that left side is odd and right side is even. This is what I wrote and I wonder how do I to find the run time.

```
for (i=0;i<size-1;i++)
        {
            if(ptr[i]%2==0 || ptr[i]==0)
            {
                for (j=i;j<size;j++)
                {
                    if(ptr[j]%2!=0)
                    {
                        temp=ptr[i];
                        ptr[i]=ptr[j];
                        ptr[j]=temp;
                        break;
                    }

                }
            }
        }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* attempt at solving this yourself?  Have you verified that the program even works properly?

Comment: "I don't know how to calculate it". Did you ask your teaching staff? If they have required you to do this then I am assuming they have covered order of complexity in their teaching and thus you must have some idea. And it's not really clear whether you actually do mean order of complexity or actual clock run time. Can you clarify?

Comment: sorry my presentations are not in english so i am trying to translate my question properly, i think i mean how do i calculate the order of complexity,in class that Taught us spesific sort methods,and didnt explain how to calculate your order of complexity yet

Answer (score 0):

Your runtime for this Code is  O(N^2)

You can use Counting Sort to sort an array in linear time 
For reference  [Counting Sort](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/counting-sort/)

Answer (score 0):

As [@VenuKant Sahu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41728408/2410359) answered, OP's code is `O(n*n)`

That is due to its double nested `for` loops

```
for (i=0;i<size-1;i++)
   ...
   for (j=i;j<size;j++)
     ...
```

---

> I need to write code that sorts in 'n' run time

O(n) algorithm  (did not want to just give the code)

The number of loop iterations below can not exceed `n/2`.
The increment even_side happens at most `n` times.
The decrement odd_side happens at most `n` times.

```
  // set up indexes
  int even_side = left-most valid index
  int odd_side = right-most valid index
  loop {
    while (the_even_index_is_not_at_the_right_end && is_even(a[even_side]) increment even_side;
    while (the_odd_index_is_not_at_the_left_end && !is_even(a[odd_side]) decrement odd_side

    compare the indexes
    if (done) exit the loop;

    a[even_side] <==> a[odd_side]
  }
```

---

Some helper code to set up a random array.

```
  #define N 10
  srand(time(NULL));
  int a[N];
  for (int i = 0; i<N; i++) {
    a[i] = rand()%100;
    printf(" %d", a[i]);
  }
  puts("");
```